# How can we progress seekbar according to chronometer increments?

Tags: android

In my app, i-e an audio recorder app,  I wish to progress seek-bar according to the time(Chronometer), that is according to the time audio records.

How it can be done?

Comment: And what have you done yet ??

Answer (score 1):

use `yourProgressBar.setProgress(VALUE_YOU_WANNA_SET)`.

in a thread which updates the UI every sec.